# Power Apps - how to clone? how to change source from SharePoint to CDS?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, common-data-service

I have agile user story which reads as follows-

- clone the power App,
- point it to CDS,
- ensure no functionality is lost.

I am given access to the app in the published apps section, how could I get to the source code?

when I opened and look at the app, it is made using tablet mode and has all bells and whistles of Canvas App, it appears.

what is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: thanks Arun. but File save as - does not show up in my case. when I exit the app it  takes me back to the published apps page where it shows all apps. there is no File save as thing

Comment: then ask someone who is Env admin to clone it and share with you by including edit privileges. Also even if you have solution extracted and checked into Azure devops, this maker experience is the only way to develop this. Two developers cannot work in parallel, just FYI

Comment: do you have followup questions?

Comment: thanks Arun for your suggestion, I could try it once I get access and let you know

Comment: thanks. clone part works. after that I exported SharePoint lists to Excel and now when I try to import it says 'you do not have privileges...'. I tried creating new entity manually then also I get same message. I could google on this error

Comment: I got required access and I have cloned the app. created approx 10 entities in CDS. for each sharepoint list I have one table in CDS. now when I go to edit the app, what is best way to replace each sharepoint list name with equivalent CDS name?

Comment: when I select Gallery name in left side Tree View panel, on the right hand side in properties - Data sources is grayed out with fx on it. should I be changing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone any app by doing this, open the canvas app and go to menu: File -> “Save as” option. This will be exact same replica.

[image]

Then you can create a new data source to CDS and point the cloned app to the new data source. Before that you have to make sure to prepare the identical schema - table and columns as initial datasource. That will make sure nothing is broken and experience is seamless. [Read more](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Duplicating-a-PowerApp/m-p/513569#M156490)

Update:

Ask someone who is Environment admin to clone it and share with you by including edit privileges. Also even if you have solution extracted and checked into Azure Devops, this maker experience is the only way to develop this. Two developers cannot work in parallel, just FYI.

Comment: It also sounds that he only has access rights, make sure you are a maker for that CDS instance and have edit privilege's for the app

Comment: correct. I do not have access to the source code or else I could have saved it with different name. the real question is how to get to the source if I only have access to some app from published apps which somebody else has developed?

Comment: @RajuChoudhari https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/share-app#share-an-app

Comment: @ArunVinoth KUDOS on the 'update' part of your answer, I frequently find myself in that position with so many tabs that get opened when editing apps '^_^

Comment: thanks Arun. the link you send is also in Microsoft training I took and this is how I share with others making my manager co-owner etc. I have requested access in similar way. let us see.